# Get CoGetClassObject from other process?

Tags: c++, process, com

I've COM object declared in process A by using `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`. So I could call `::CoGetClassObject` from this process and get this object.

Could I call `::CoGetClassObject` to get COM object of process A from process B, that was just created?

P.S. Process A is still running.

P.S.S. No info about this COM object was found in registry. :-(

Comment: Please consider rewriting the question, as it cannot be understood as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no data in the registry, then no, `::CoGetClassObject` can't work cross-process.  How would it know to look in process A?